# Declare the same non-member function twice?

Tags: c++

I have class A and Class B

I am define a non member method using A and B

```
double operator*(const A& a, const B& b);
```

Is it good to declare this into A.h and B.h at the same time since it can be considered as belong to both A and B?

Comment: You can have as many declarations as you want. So yes. But don't define it in the header unless it's marked `inline`.

Comment: I think its better to declare in a common.h and include it in booth A.h and B.h

Comment: Shouldn't it be `double operator*(const B& b);` in class `A` or `double operator*(const A& a);` in class `B`?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: Only if you want it to be a member of one or the other for some reason. A non-member would often be better, especially if it doesn't need privileged access to either class.

Comment: @MikeSeymour If not define it in either class, how will you call it (I mean, how to handle the `*this`)?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: You'd call it like any other binary operator, `some_A * some_B`. There won't be a `this`, just two function parameters.

Comment: If A does not depend on B and B not on A, have an additional header.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it good to declare this into A.h and B.h at the same time since it can be considered as belong to both A and B?

It is possible to declare it like that since it is just the declaration, and not definition. Other than that, it is probably just personal taste whether to do it so, or put it into a common header, and so on.